# How to set the accessibility label of the alert message in iOS?

Tags: ios, uialertcontroller, voiceover, uiaccessibility

I have `UIAlertController` with a message. I want the alert message accessibility label to be different than the alert message string.

How can I do that?

Comment: try to set the alert controller title accessibility label.

Comment: thanks, but the alert controller title is a String, I can't assign it accessibility label

Answer (score -1):

you can find each `UIControl` element using `subviews` array.

For example if you want to change `accessibilityLabel` of your `UIAlertController` you can do this:

```
let contentTitleForAlert = myAlertController.view.subviews[0].subviews[0].subviews[0].subviews[0].subviews[0].subviews[0]
        contentTitleForAlert.accessibilityLabel = "¡My text for accessibility label"
```

Using this way you can change other elements in the `UIAlertController`. For example:

```
let contentLabelForAlert = myalertController.view.subviews[0].subviews[0].subviews[0].subviews[0].subviews[0].subviews[1]
        contentLabelForAlert.accessibilityLabel = "Text for accessibilityLabel for main content in UIAlertController."
```